# Heroku run 'No Module Named Pip' issue

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I'm trying to run `heroku run python3 -m pip install 'package'` in the console, but when I do so it returns `/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip`. I want to install a package manually before pushing to heroku with git.

It's really frustrating so I hope someone knows how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: does -m pip3 work?

Comment: Nope, same error.

Comment: Why not using requirements.txt?

Comment: Well I need to install pafy from github, because there's an issue with the 'official' pafy and youtube dislikes. And when pafy from github is being installed, it returns an error of 'No module named youtube-dl', so I thought, maybe install it manually before pip installs from the requirements file to avoid this error. Youtube-dl is in my requirements.txt file tho, so it seems like a weird bug

Answer (score -1):

there,
You most install python3-pip and python-dev in your system,
ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip python-dev`
fedora: `sudo dnf install python3-pip python-dev`
Arch: `sudo pacman -Syu python3-pip python-dev`
and then use:

```
pip install package
```

Comment: Okay but i'm on windows so what are the commands then?